# Insert statement conflicted with the Foreign key

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

Here I try to insert data in fact table from another source database tables here is the query which I try

```
alter procedure spfactinsert
as
insert into [pp dw].dbo.Dimfact(costprice,Prod_ID,Production_ID,MaterialQuantity,Quantity)

select [cost price],Products.[Product ID],Production_Detail.[ProdDetail ID],
[Material Quantity],Production_Detail.Quantity
 from
[PRODUCTION PLANNING 2].dbo.Production_Detail,
[PRODUCTION PLANNING 2].dbo.[Materials],
[PRODUCTION PLANNING 2].dbo.[Recipies],
[PRODUCTION PLANNING 2].dbo.Products

where 
Production_Detail.[ProdDetail ID]='1' and
[Materials].[Material ID]='1' and
[Recipies].[Recipy ID]='1'
and
Products.[Product ID]='13'
```

but it shows me error

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Dimfact_DimProduction". The conflict occurred in database "pp dw", table "dbo.DimProduction", column 'Production_ID'.
```

ERD IS 
[IMAGE ERD](http://i58.tinypic.com/2nq8r2s.jpg)

How do I solve this?

Comment: Come on use better formatting.  So does DimProduction have a Production_ID of 1.  Your where is Production_Detail.[ProdDetail ID]='1'.  Those cross joins with no on seem odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first column in the insert list is `Quantity` but you select `cost price` which is the 2nd column in the insert list.  You are inserting `Quantity` as `Production_ID` causing the FK violation.

Change to:

```
insert into [pp dw].dbo.Dimfact(Quantity,costprice,Prod_ID,MaterialQuantity,Production_ID)
SELECT 
    Production_Detail.Quantity,
    [cost price],
    Production_Detail.[ProdDetail ID],
    [Material Quantity],
    Products.[Product ID]
```